# WPF/C# Label Content to ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, label

I have a WPF/C# app with a tiny issue. I have a label that is passing the string value of AZ. I have a combobox that has AX, AY, and AZ values bound to the database. For some reason, the label value is not matching to the combobox value.

So, I have

CbCode.SelectedValue = Code;

Code is coming from another window

```
public SystemCode(string Code)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Code = sysCode;
}

public string Code { get; }
```

The debugger tells me the string value is AZ, bu the combobox in the screen is the default the value of AX.

So how do I get the label content to set the page load value of the combobox?

**XAML:**

```
<ComboBox x:Name="CbCode" DataContext="{StaticResource CodeViewSource}"
SelectedValuePath="Code" ItemsSource="{Binding}" DisplayMemberPath="Code"
HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="106,103,0,116.4" Width="97"
d:LayoutOverrides="Height"/> <TextBox x:Name="TxtZipFive"
HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="106,0,0,85.4"
TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="97"/>
```

Comment: Can you please show me your XAML?

Comment: There's a lot of information missing in your answer. Edit your answer and show us how are you binding the combobox and your xaml.

Comment: <ComboBox x:Name="CbCode" DataContext="{StaticResource CodeViewSource}"
                          SelectedValuePath="Code" ItemsSource="{Binding}" DisplayMemberPath="Code" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="106,103,0,116.4" Width="97" d:LayoutOverrides="Height"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="TxtZipFive" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="106,0,0,85.4" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Width="97"/>

Comment: MetroWindow_Loaded
CbState.SelectedValue = State;
var dataSet1CodeTableAdapater = new CodeTableAdapter();
            dataSet1CodeTableAdapater.FillCode(dataSet1.Code);
            var codeViewSource = (CollectionViewSource)FindResource("CodeViewSource");
            codeViewSource.View.MoveCurrentToFirst();

Comment: Where is the XAML of your Label?

Comment: Label value is coming from another window. Let's say Window1.xaml has the label. Window2.xaml has the combobox

Comment: <Label x:Name="LblCode" Content="Label" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Visibility="Hidden" Margin="0,3.4,211.8,14.6" Grid.Row="1" Width="38"/>

Comment: Can you please upload your project on google drive and paste the link here?

Comment: Instead of pasting your code as a comment, edit your question and paste it there please

Comment: You have set the DataContext to be a static resource of CodeViewSource. You should not need to set the DataContext. CodeViewSource should be a property on your ViewModel and you should bind to it that way. The problem is that your ComboBox does not have the same DataContext as your Label.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear enough, but I think you need to use:

```
UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged
```